# Let $M$ be a complex manifold. Why are the bundles $\bigwedge^{p, q}M$ not holomorphic vector bundles over $M$ for $q \neq 0$ ?

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles, complex-manifolds, holomorphic-bundles

Let $M$ be a complex manifold. Can anyone help me understand why 
$\bigwedge^{p, q}M$ are not holomorphic vector bundles over $M$ for $q \neq 0$ ? I think it suffices to show that the transition maps are not holomorphic, but how are they defined ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to look at what is, say, $\Lambda^{0,1} \mathbb C$?

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki Yes, but how to generalize this to $\bigwedge^{p, q}\mathbb{C}$ ? This is somehow unclear to me.

Comment: You can look at the transition functions. As long as you have some $d\overline{z}_i$ the transition function will imply conjugates of $\mathbb C$-linear maps, which are of course not $\mathbb C$-linear.